# How to create a thumbnail playlist for a music player in android?

Tags: android, imageview, thumbnails, grid-layout, audio-player, android-music-player

I developed a simple media player app in android. It has a list view to load all songs in SD card, seek bar and play button. I need to create a album art gallery for my app (Like in google play music app). I used this code to get all songs from SD card,

```
public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(DirectoryPath);
        f.mkdirs();
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }else {
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
        }

        return MyFiles;
    }
```

1. How to improve this code to return song name and album-art?
2. How to create a thumbnail view for each song ?

   ```
    _________
   |         |
   | image   |
   |         |
   |_________|
   |  title  |
   |_________|
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use content resolver.

---

```
 Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            // Perform a query on the content resolver. The URI we're passing specifies that we
            // want to query for all audio media on external storage (e.g. SD card)
            Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(uri, null,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1", null, null);
            if (cur == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to retrieve music: cursor is null :-(");
                subscriber.onError(new Throwable("Failed to retrieve music: cursor is null :-("));
                return;
            }
            if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                subscriber.onError(new Throwable("No results. :( Add some tracks!"));

                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to move cursor to first row (no query results).");
                return;
            }
            int artistColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int titleColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int albumColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
            int durationColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
            int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int dataColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            ArrayList<LocalTrack> tracks = new ArrayList<>();

            do {
                Log.i(TAG, "ID: " + cur.getString(idColumn) + " Title: " + cur.getString(titleColumn));
                tracks.add(new LocalTrack(
                        cur.getLong(idColumn),
                        cur.getString(artistColumn),
                        cur.getString(titleColumn),
                        cur.getLong(albumColumn),
                        cur.getLong(durationColumn),
                        cur.getString(dataColumn)));
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
            Log.i(TAG, "Done querying media. MusicRetriever is ready.");
            cur.close();


            for (LocalTrack localTrack : tracks) {
                localTrack.setArtPath(findAlbumArt(localTrack));
            }
            subscriber.onNext(tracks);
```

---

```
public String findAlbumArt(LocalTrack localTrack) {
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(localTrack.getAlbum())},
            null);

    String path = null;
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
            // do whatever you need to do
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return path;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that

Comment: If you want to see the all project : https://github.com/joxad/zikobot

The part you may use : https://github.com/joxad/zikobot/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/startogamu/zikobot/module/content_resolver/manager/LocalMusicManager.java

It uses dagger 2 , but you should be able to update it to your needs

Comment: Thank you. I'll try